# What's the difference between SRL and SRA?

Tags: assembly, mips, bit-shift, instructions

What changes when using the instruction `sra` and the `srl` one? I can't understand the difference between the two. The language in use is MIPS assembly.

```
sll $t1,$t0,2
sra $t2,$t0,2

sll $t1,$t0,2
srl $t2,$t0,2
```

Comment: You might want to specify *which* assembly language you're interested in (probably ARM). There *are* quite a few different CPUs in the world :-)

Comment: Sorry about that haha, the language is actually MIPS.

Comment: If the right shifts took their input from the result of the left shift, these snippets would be zero- or sign-extending from 30 bits to 32 bits, respectively.  But they're not, the left shift is independent in both cases so IDK why it's repeated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SLR** is a typo and should be **SRL** instead. `SRA` does an [arithmetic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) and `SRL` does a [logical one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift). So `SRL` will shift zeros in whereas `SRA` shifts the sign bit in. For example shifting 0xFFFF1234 right logically gives 0x3FFFC48D and arithmetically gives 0xFFFFC48D because the sign bit is 1 (assuming this is MIPS32). For more information read

- [Please explain the difference between logical shift right, arithmatic shift right, and rotate right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44694957/995714)
- [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/141525/995714)

Comment: The typo in the question is only in the title.  Probably we should just fix that.  `slr` isn't a valid mnemonic at all, according to the assembler in MARS.  IDK why you're saying it's a left shift; MIPS's left shift is `sll`.